# myfile.open isn't working correctly and cout does not show data

Tags: c++

I don't get why the program isn't outputting "status" to the console.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    cout << "Hello!\n";

    ifstream myfile;  **Am I using this correctly?**
    ofstream pot;
    char status;
    string fname, lname, phone, address;

    myfile.open("potentials.txt");  **myfile.open isnt opening**   

    myfile >> status;    
    myfile >> fname;    
    myfile >> lname;     
    myfile >> phone;

    cout << status; **status is not outputting to console when I run**
    cout << fname;  **Any ideas?**

    cout << "Hello. \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read from or write to a file?  Status is never given a value.

Comment: @LukePark I'm trying to read from the file, and then write to it after I write the rest of the program... I'm confused why my youtube link wasn't in the stackoverflow like how i remember putting it there, heres a link to it [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbA5Mvo8IPg)

Comment: @LukePark Here's a 2nd video where I try to run the same code in a virtual machine. It crashes the Dev-C++ Program every single time I try to run it [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvKRC5Pp8wc)

Comment: What is contained in potentials.txt?  And where is it stored?

Comment: @LukePark just a file that has information from which I am suppose to continue the rest of the Lab, depending on what the input is my program should do etc etc etc.

However, I could not move forward because I could not get the program to open the file... thus, I couldnt do anything else. Heres a link to made explaining WHERE the .txt file is located [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TPViDBThuM)

Comment: The file has to be in the executing directory.  Where you have it is not in the executing directory...  Try using a full path to the file.

Comment: @Luke [Success!!!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLEfoKgApYg&feature=youtu.be)

Future readers of this post. Explicitly name the path through the directories to the file as demonstrated by the above link.

Comment: I'll edit my answer.  Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open` method of an input file stream requires the second parameter.  Try changing the line:

`myfile.open("potentials.txt");`

to

`myfile.open("potentials.txt", std::ifstream::in);`

EDIT: Or just open the file when you declare `myfile` like so:

`ifstream myfile("potentials.txt");`

If this still isn't working, you are likely not opening the file correctly.  E.g. wrong directory.  Use a full path to the file.

Comment: doesn't 'using namespace std;' mean that I shouldnt have to do that? Thats what my professor has led me to believe, during class today she was vexed as well, and allowed me to directly copy a fellows students code. It still would not work though [link](http://imgur.com/TjN88mc)

Comment: Well, if you want to be particular, just `ifstream::in` then.  It doesn't change the number of required parameters for a method...

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your code and it worked for me, though I'm using Visual Studio 2015. BUT, This is the code if you want to read everything in the file. I hope it helps!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {



    ifstream myfile;  
    ofstream pot;
    char status;
    string fname, lname, phone, address;

    myfile.open("potentials.txt",ios::in);  

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (!myfile.eof()) {
            myfile >> status;
            myfile >> fname;
            myfile >> lname;
            myfile >> phone;

            cout << status << " ";
            cout << fname << " ";
            cout << lname << " ";
            cout << phone << "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n File not open!";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions just ask!

Also, usually, if the file does not open either it means you don't have reading privileges, or there is no file named "potentiality" in the directory you're specifying. This example expects it in the same directory as the .cpp file.

Comment: @Dyrenez I created  a youtube video while in the middle of class today demonstrating how it was in fact compiling and running [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbA5Mvo8IPg) However, the 'cout << status' doesn't register. Although the first video I made in class did not have the potentially.txt file in the same directory, I corrected that problem and it continued to persist, the fact the 'cout << status' was not working. 
Here is a second video I made later in the day showing how the same code run in a different IDE kept crashing. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvKRC5Pp8wc)

Comment: @Dyrenez Here is a video I made demonstrating how the .txt file is in the EXACT same folder, but it DOES NOT open... [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TPViDBThuM)